# Shortest route to intersection

Tags: math, vector, collision

I asked this question about 2 months ago but found none of the answers to be helpful enough. So I am giving it another shot. I think it was my fault not describing it well enough. So lets try again.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bja888.com](http://storage.bja888.com/collide.png))</sub>

Here is a rough idea of what I am trying to accomplish. 
The goal is to send a projectile from point T to intercept the object represented by point R.
What is known:

1. The location of object R
2. The direction object R is traveling
3. The speed at which object R is traveling
4. The location of object T
5. Speed at which object T will travel

I am looking for the direction object T should be sent and thus find the location they will collide at. Either one.

For example: If...

1. The location of R was (1,5)
2. R is traveling at a 45 degree angle (relative to d)
3. R is traveling at 1 unit per second
4. T is located at (1,1)
5. T also travels at 1 unit per second

[image]
<sub>(source: [bja888.com](http://storage.bja888.com/proof.png))</sub>

L makes the location of the collision at (3,3)

Comment: You work for the Department of Defense, don't you? You're working on an auto-targeting turret, aren't you? You kill people, don't you? ;-)

Comment: Same concept. But for a game.

Comment: Must *T* travel in a straight line?

Comment: Yes. However, I am considering adding the option for a seeking projectile. I also need to keep in mind that R might be faster then T.

Comment: When you get to seeking projectiles you will need to grasp 'pursuit curves'.

Comment: I assume you are not looking for just *any* collision; there are infinite of those.  Your title says *shortest route*, but I see no reference to that in the question; do you mean that you want **T** to have to travel the shortest distance, or you want **R** and **T** to collide at the earliest time possible?

Comment: ... or do you want **R** and **T** to be fired at the same time?  All three of these questions have different answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of possibilities.  Consider a concentric series of circles from the points R and T, representing the distance each could travel at increasing times.  Where the circles intersect is the point of collision, a vector between the point of collision and T is where T should have been aimed at for that particular instant.  If you *are* looking for the shortest path, you need to get the normal to R's path and fire T at the appropriate time by calculating the time it takes for T to traverse this distance so it will arrive at the same time as R.

Comment: The speed of *T* is fixed (assumption 5), so there are at most 2 possibilities.

Comment: A duck hunter shooting a duck with a shotgun can shoot over a wide timeframe even though the speed of the shot isn't affected, right?

Comment: Or maybe you're assuming that R and T must be fired at the same instant?

Answer (score 0):

Assume no air friction, gravity, external forces, near-speed-of-light missiles, violation of physical laws, etc.

Suppose initially *R* = (*x*, *y*) and *T* = (0, 0). (Change your coordinates system if *T* not at the origin).

Suppose the velocity of *T* is constantly (cos *θ*, sin *θ*), where *θ* is unknown but does not depend on time. (Change your coordinates system or unit of time if the speed if not 1.)

Suppose the velocity of *R* is constantly (*v*, 0). (Change your coordinates system if the velocity is not along the horizontal.)

Suppose at time *t* the two objects collide. So we have 2 equations and 2 unknowns:

- *t* cos *θ* = *x* + *vt*
- *t* sin *θ* = *y*

So obviously

- *t*<sup>2</sup> = (*x* + *vt*)<sup>2</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>.

Solve this quadratic equation to get *t*. Plug it into the *y* equation to get *θ*. QED.

Comment: I only see the speed of R. Where is the speed of T taken into account?

Comment: @Jacks: It's defined to be 1. (Change your coordinates system or unit of time if the speed if not 1.)

Comment: Here is what I got for the quadratic...
http://storage.bja888.com/find-time.png

The problem is, if the velocity of R is 1 unit/second it will always try to divide by 0. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Jacks: If *v* = 1 you get 0/0. Make it a special case.